# OneSignal pedindo URL com APP_ID do SDK?

Tags: api

Eu estou utilizando o código do `OneSignal` e não estou a conseguir efetuar a subscrição dos utilizadores, pois ao aceitar, ele dá um erro `A bad HTTP response code (403) was received when fetching the script.`. Ele vai buscar o ficheiro `OneSignalSDKWorker.js`mas ainda pede o meu APP_ID junto, mesmo não especificando esse pedido, ou seja, pede isto `/OneSignalSDKWorker.js?appId=A_MINHA_APP_ID`.

Eis o código

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async=""></script>
<script>
  var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
      appId: "A_MINHA_APP_ID",
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na doc do OneSignal, a chamada para isso é diferente:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk

```
var OneSignal = OneSignal || [];

OneSignal.push(["init", {
  appId: "YOUR_APP_ID",
  // Your other init settings
}]);
```

Nota que isso vai de versão para versão, ja tive problemas com isso por um detalhe besta que eles mudaram e todos meus apps param de funcionar o push.

Comment: Did it, still the same